# Swagger allOf not respected when using SwaggerHub code generator

Tags: code-generation, swagger-2.0, swaggerhub

I am trying to generate a python SDK for the following API definition:

https://api.youneedabudget.com/papi/spec-v1-swagger.json

When I load the json on swaggerhub everything seems fine, but the generated python code is missing some fields in the models.

As an example, consider the `transactionDetail` model; it should contain all the fields of `TransactionSummary`. In the swaggerhub interface, the model shows up correctly:

[image: Swagger screenshot]

But in the generated python, the `swagger_types` are as follows:

```
    swagger_types = {
        'account_name': 'str',
        'payee_name': 'str',
        'category_name': 'str',
        'subtransactions': 'list[SubTransaction]'
    }
```

Basically missing everything from `TransactionSummary`.

I feel I am missing a tiny simple detail, but I am no expert in this field and was unable to solve the issue.

Comment: Open a ticket with [SwaggerHub support](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/message/). Alternatively, try [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/).

Comment: Thans @Helen, OpenAPI worked as expected.